# Why doesn't CodeIgniter use native PHP Sessions?

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies, codeigniter-2

The PHP Framework "CodeIgniter" provides a Session Class, which does not use native PHP-Sessions. Instead, they developped an own Session system using Cookies.

On their Website [CodeIgniter.com](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) they write the following:

```
Note: The Session class does not utilize native PHP sessions. It generates its own session data, offering more flexibility for developers.
```

As also mentioned below, only a maximum of 4KB can be saved.

```
Note: Cookies can only hold 4KB of data, so be careful not to exceed the capacity. The encryption process in particular produces a longer data string than the original so keep careful track of how much data you are storing.
```

So, how does this give more flexibility to the programmer at all? What was the actual Reason of the developers to **not** use native PHP Sessions?

Thank you for your Information!

Comment: You need to ask the CI developers (http://codeigniter.com/forums/). This question can only elicit opinions and arguments in this venue.